# Efficient Algorithm to calculate Ax=b for underdetermined system using Moore-penrose

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

I have a tremendous, fat and sparse matrix A and I need to solve Ax=b just one single time, so if possible I don't want to calculate the Moore-Penrose Inverse explicitly (using SVD or similar).
What is the smartest way to do that?

Comment: Gaussian elimination is pretty much always the best way to solve a single $Ax = b$ equation. You only worry about inverses and the rest when you need more than the solution of one linear equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Once I do the gaussian elimination is it hard to get an orthonormal basis for the nullspace of A? Also I suppose doing gaussian elimination just leads to one possible solution to Ax=b, not the generalised one?

Comment: That falls under "need more than the solution of one linear equation". G.E. gives you the general solution, and with a little more work will give you *a* basis for the null-space. But in general, that basis is not orthonormal. If that is needed, you'd have to do orthogonalization afterwards. At that point, it is probably no longer the most efficient method.